# TypeError: number is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

I'm developing a text-based game, and I have a function (`turn()`) that determines the user's action based on what button they press.

But every time you press one of the 3 buttons, the console says `TypeError: number is not a function`.

I've tried many operations (such as moving all of my scripts into one file, defining the game's variable globally, and changing the order of the functions), but it still doesn't work!

Any help?

---

**JavaScript code:**

```js
console.log("Resetting resources...");
var turn = 1;
var player = {
  damage: Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 2), //Deals 2 to 5 damage
  healing: Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 3), //Heals 3 to 6 health
  health: null,
  maxHP: 25, //Maximum health (not recommended to change)
  special: true,
  alive: true
};
var dragon = {
  damage: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1), //Deals 1 to 6 damage
  health: null,
  maxHP: 28, //Maximum health (not recommended to change)
  alive: true
};
player.health = player.maxHP;
dragon.health = dragon.maxHP;
console.log("Resources ready!");

function turn() {
  if (player.alive) {
    /*Player turn*/
    console.log("---------------TURN " + turn + " : PLAYER---------------");
    alert("The dragon is still alive!");
    console.log("Player HP: " + player.health + "/" + player.maxHP);

    switch (action) {
      case '1':
        console.log("Dealt " + player.damage + " damage!");
        dragon.health -= player.damage;
        if (dragon.health <= 0) {
          alert("The dragon has been slain!");
          console.log("---------------DRAGON SLAIN---------------");
          dragon.alive = false;
          player.alive = false;
        }
        break;
      case '2':
        console.log("Recovered " + player.healing + " health!");
        player.health += player.healing;
        break;
      case '3':
        alert("Scared of dying, you ditch the scene before you become human toast.");
        console.log("---------------PLAYER SURRENDERS---------------");
        player.alive = false;
        break;
      default:
        console.error("Random error occured.");
        break;
    }

    /*Reset RNG*/
    player.damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 2);
    player.healing = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 3);

    /*Dragon turn*/
    console.log("---------------TURN " + turn + " : DRAGON---------------");
    console.log("Dragon HP: " + dragon.health + "/" + dragon.maxHP);
    console.log("Dealt " + dragon.damage + " damage!");
    player.health -= dragon.damage;
    if (player.health <= 0) {
      alert("You have died!");
      console.log("---------------PLAYER DIES---------------");
      player.alive = false;
    }
    /*Reset RNG*/
    dragon.damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    turn++;
  } else if (!player.alive && dragon.alive) {
    alert("You have died!\nGAME OVER\nReset the game to play again.");
  } else if (!dragon.alive) {
    alert("You have slain the dragon!\nGAME OVER\nReset the game to play again.");
  }
}

function attack() {
  turn('1'); //Error occurs here
}

function heal() {
  turn('2'); //and here
}

function flee() {
  turn('3'); // and here
}
```

```html
<button onclick="attack()">Attack</button>
<button onclick="heal()">Heal</button>
<button onclick="flee()">Flee!</button>
```

Comment: You have `var turn = 1` and `function turn()`. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `turn` to be a variable at the beginning of the script: `var turn = 1;`.

Then you are trying to redefine it later as a function: `function turn() { ... }`.

The "problem" is that JavaScript put function definition at the beginning of the block, after variable definition but prior to variable assignment, so in reality your JavaScript code will be interpreted as:

```
var turn;

function turn() { ... }

turn = 1;
```

The end result is in fact that `turn` is a number (`1`) and this is not a function, so you can't call it with `turn('1')`.